# How to open/close a bootstrap modal without triggering event?

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

I have a bootstrap modal that trigger additional actions when opened or closed manually. These actions are hooked with `show.bs.modal` and `hide.bs.modal` events.

Now I want to also be able to open or close modal programmatically without triggering this action. Is it possible?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need a way of determining how the modal was triggered; a flag or similar.

According to the [Bootstrap documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals-events) (assuming you're using version 3), `e.relatedTarget` is set as the element which was clicked for the `show.bs.modal` event in your callback. Thus, `e.relatedTarget` is undefined if triggered programmatically.  You can use this to avoid your `show.bs.modal` callback function from running. For example:

```
$('#myModal').on('show.bs.modal', function (e) {
  if (e.relatedTarget) {
    // User triggered, do something...
  }
});
```

As for the `hide.bs.modal` event, there isn't a similar attribute available, but you could achieve the same effect with a toggle class or data attribute.  Set this flag just before you're about to hide your modal in your code, and ensure that your modal's `hide.bs.modal` callback is checking for its presence, and only run if not present. For example:

```
// Prep modal event
$('#myModal').on('hide.bs.modal', function (e) {
    if (!$('#myModal').hasClass('programmatic')) {
        // User triggered, do something...
    }
});

// When hiding your modal
$('#myModal').toggleClass('programmatic');
$('#myModal').modal('hide');
```

For both of the above cases, another option is to remove your event listener before showing/hiding, trigger the modal to be shown/hidden, and re-add the event listener.